# Visual Studio 2015 IntelliTest: CLR detected an Invalid Program

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-4.0, intellitest

So I am trying out the IntelliTest feature on VS2015 and I can't seem to get it to work for my Imported MVC 3.0 using .NET 4.0 application. I tired running the test on controller methods, public static methods or even separate projects of type Class Library (public static or public methods).

The error I keep getting boils down to CLR detected an invalid program.

I created a new test solution and the IntelliTest seemed to work. I am aware that it doesn't work on x64 so I even changed my configuration of the build to x86 and still nothing.

Any suggestions on how to make an MVC project work with IntelliTest? Am I missing a piece of the puzzle?

Comment: Just as a head's up, you don't actually need to add a signature to your posts. The user box that gets added to your posts serves as your signature: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Try this: go to the IntelliTrace section in the "Options..." dialog and select "IntelliTrace events only". If it works, then it's some problem stemming from the IntelliTrace profiler. Do you have any other profiler-based tools installed, like TypeMock or JustMock?

Comment: I tried both options and still have the same issue. I am even trying to create a factory class to see if I can override or tweak the creation or maybe even debug the test run. So far no luck!